# How I can use io.emit )

Tags: node.js, twitter, socket.io

I am working on twitter bot with node.js. I wanna realtime data, but i don't work socket.io  How can i use io.emit or io.socket.emit ? 
[My code is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p6oP.png)

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pisCE.png)

Comment: Please don't post images when you can copy-paste the text instead. It would be much easier to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

socket.io website is down and the documentation is moved to here: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/tree/master/docs

Assuming `io` is the Socket.IO namespace on server side.

`io.sockets.emit` is equivalent to `io.emit`, and `io.socket.emit` is not a documented function (I see that you used `io.sockets.emit` in your code example). What this does is it sends an event to all connected clients. `io.emit` does not have a documented return value.

Flag `sockets` is for backward compatibility, in most code examples, you'll see `io.emit` without `sockets` flag. Other flags includes `volatile` and `local`.

Comment: The socket.io website is not down anymore: http://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/socket.io

Comment: @Frxstrem Oh, nice! It was down for a couple weeks, finally back up online again :D